# How to handle dependencies between Angular form controls?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm developing an Angular (12) reactive form with lots of direct and indirect dependencies between the form control values.
Example:
The tax rate is dependent on the selected country, the date and the selected receipt type, but it can also be set manually. Changes of the tax rate trigger changes to the net amount. But the net amount can also be set manually with leads to changes of the gross amount. And so on...

I tried to handle these dependencies with the form control valueChanges subscriptions and with on blur events of the control components, but this ends up in an event handler hell where one change overwrites the other.

What is the way to handle complex dependencies between Angular reactive form controls in a clean, clear and maintainable way? I couldn't find a suitable example for this.

Comment: Sounds more like logic problem not related to forms at all. Lets say you have class with 10 fields and 10 changeSmth() methods -- will it make situation easier?

Comment: The logic is complex indeed, this is what my question is about. I habe no idea how I could simplify it because it represents the functional requirements

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar input dependency issues by writing custom validators, the angular tutorial is called "Adding Cross Validation to Reactive Forms".

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms

Doing this, you can group your validators (if needed), and make sure that the correct dependency tree is present based on the user's selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure if I got you right - my question is not about form validation but about form control value changes.

Comment: I understand your question :), you can force certain values based on the cross field validation. For instance, if I have field that I set to USA, you can use a cross field validation pattern to force the Tax Rate field to be a certain value, have certain validations, etc.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to me to change the form value within a validator as this is not what a validator is supposed to do. I don't think this would make the whole thing more clear